# Caliburn.Micro nested ViewModels

Tags: c#, beginner, mvvm

I am currently developing a small tool intended to help me keep track of the myriad of characters in my Stories.

The tool does the following:

- Load the characters which are currently stored as json on the disk and stores them in a list, which is presented in the Shell via a ListBox.
- If the user then opens a character the Shell, which is a `Conductor<Screen>.Collection.OneActive`, opens a new `CharacterViewModel`, that derives from `Screen`.
- The `Character` gets the Character that is going to be opened via the `IEventAggregator` message system.
- The `CharacterViewModel` furthermore has various properties which are sub ViewModels which bind to various sub Views.

And here is my Problem:
Currently I initialize the sub ViewModels manually when the `ChracterViewModel` is initialized. But this sounds fishy to me and I am pretty sure there is a better way to do this, but I cannot see how I should do it.

Here is the code of the `CharacterViewModel`:

```
/// <summary>ViewModel for the character view.</summary>
public class CharacterViewModel : Screen, IHandle<DataMessage<ICharacterTagsService>>
{
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Fields
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /// <summary>The event aggregator.</summary>
    private readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;

    /// <summary>The character tags service.</summary>
    private ICharacterTagsService characterTagsService;

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructors & Destructors
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CharacterViewModel"/> class.</summary>
    public CharacterViewModel()
    {
        if (Execute.InDesignMode)
        {
            this.CharacterGeneralViewModel = new CharacterGeneralViewModel();

            this.CharacterMetadataViewModel = new CharacterMetadataViewModel();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CharacterViewModel"/> class.</summary>
    /// <param name="eventAggregator">The event aggregator.</param>
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public CharacterViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        : this()
    {
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        this.eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Properties
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the character.</summary>
    public Character Character { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the character general view model.</summary>
    public CharacterGeneralViewModel CharacterGeneralViewModel { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the character metadata view model.</summary>
    public CharacterMetadataViewModel CharacterMetadataViewModel { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the character characteristics view model.</summary>
    public CharacterApperanceViewModel CharacterCharacteristicsViewModel { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the character family view model.</summary>
    public CharacterFamilyViewModel CharacterFamilyViewModel { get; set; }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Methods
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /// <summary>Saves a character to the file system as a json file.</summary>
    public void SaveCharacter()
    {
        ICharacterSaveService saveService = new JsonCharacterSaveService(Constants.CharacterSavePathMyDocuments);

        saveService.SaveCharacter(this.Character);

        this.characterTagsService.AddTags(this.Character.Metadata.Tags);
        this.characterTagsService.SaveTags();
    }

    /// <summary>Called when initializing.</summary>
    protected override void OnInitialize()
    {
        this.CharacterGeneralViewModel = new CharacterGeneralViewModel(this.eventAggregator);
        this.CharacterMetadataViewModel = new CharacterMetadataViewModel(this.eventAggregator, this.Character);
        this.CharacterCharacteristicsViewModel = new CharacterApperanceViewModel(this.eventAggregator, this.Character);
        this.CharacterFamilyViewModel = new CharacterFamilyViewModel(this.eventAggregator);

        this.eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread(new CharacterMessage
        {
            Data = this.Character
        });


        base.OnInitialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
    public void Handle(DataMessage<ICharacterTagsService> message)
    {
        this.characterTagsService = message.Data;
    }
}
```

For Completion Sake I also give you one of the sub ViewModels. The others a of no importance because they are structured the same way, just perform different tasks.

```
/// <summary>The character metadata view model.</summary>
public class CharacterMetadataViewModel : Screen
{
    /// <summary>The event aggregator.</summary>
    private readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;

    /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CharacterMetadataViewModel"/> class.</summary>
    public CharacterMetadataViewModel()
    {
        if (Execute.InDesignMode)
        {
            this.Character = DesignData.LoadSampleCharacter();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CharacterMetadataViewModel"/> class.</summary>
    /// <param name="eventAggregator">The event aggregator.</param>
    /// <param name="character">The character.</param>
    public CharacterMetadataViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, Character character)
    {
        this.Character = character;

        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        this.eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
    }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the character.</summary>
    public Character Character { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the characters tags.
    /// </summary>
    public string Tags
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Join("; ", this.Character.Metadata.Tags);
        }

        set
        {
            char[] delimiters = { ',', ';', ' ' };

            List<string> tags = value.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

            this.Character.Metadata.Tags = tags;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.Tags);
        }
    }
}
```

I already read in on [Screens, Conductors and Composition](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/composition), [IResult and Coroutines](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/coroutines) and skimmed the rest of the Documentation, but somehow I cannot find what I am looking for.

I should mention the code I have works just fine. I'm just not satisfied with it, since I think I am not understanding the concept of MVVM quite right and therefore make faulty code.

Answer (score 5):

### Comments

I need to comment on ...your comments. Really. **NONE** of the comments you have here are useful.

None of them.

---

#### Xml comments

This is rather unusual:

> ```
> /// <summary>ViewModel for the character view.</summary>
> ```

Normally XML comments looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// ViewModel for the character view.
/// </summary>
```

That's also how the IDE sets them up automatically for you when you type `///` (assuming Visual Studio), so having them on 1 line seems like you're fighting your IDE. Embrace it!

The purpose of XML comments is to provide documentation, specifically for the *public API*. This:

> ```
> /// <summary>The event aggregator.</summary>
> private readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
> ```

...is overkill useless clutter. If you *need* a comment that says "The event aggregator" for a private field called `eventAggregator` of type `IEventAggregator`, ... same here:

> ```
> /// <summary>The character tags service.</summary>
> private ICharacterTagsService characterTagsService;
> ```

---

#### Banner comments

This is rather annoying:

> ```
> // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> // Fields
> // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

Kill it, with fire. Burn. The maintainer that cannot tell a field from a property shouldn't be maintaining your code. The only thing worse you could have done, is wrap them in a `#region Fields`.

---

### This

I find the `this` qualifier adds to the clutter, although here it's needed:

> ```
> public CharacterViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
>     : this()
> {
>     this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
>     this.eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
> }
> ```

...but only because `eventAggregator` isn't called `_eventAggregator`. All other instances of `this` can be removed.

That said...

---

#### Constructor chaining

You have it reversed: the parameterless/default constructor should be calling the parameterized constructor, not the other way around:

```
public CharacterViewModel()
    : this(null)
{
    // ...
}
```

Why are you injecting an `IEventAggregator` (which is good), but instantiating `CharacterGeneralViewModel` and `CharacterMetadataViewModel`? They could be constructor-injected as well.

Comment: Regarding the usage of `this`. Actually Stylecop and ReSharper tell me to use `this`. Since I personally feel it makes the code more readable and according to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449324/stylecop-tells-me-to-add-this-keyword-but-its-redundant-any-performance-impl] (this) SO Question it makes no difference I will keep it. 
As for contructor chaining: I always thought you chained the constructor from more to less. Is there any reason to it the other way around?

Comment: To `this` or not to `this` is really more of a preference, I should have pointed out that I like your consistency here. As for constructors, chaining so as to always end up calling that with the most parameters allows you to move more code to a single constructor, and makes the defaults more obvious (you have an implicit `null` default with the parameterless constructor); it's all about *maintainability* ;)